# Nginx unable to select upstream intermittently

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have Nginx server which reverse proxy to another Nginx server via AWS private link.

Flow:
Nginx(A)-->AWS Private link--> Nginx(B)-->AWS ALB --> AWS ECS Service.

Sometimes Nginx(A) is unable to choose an upstream from upstream block and prints upstream group name in the upstream_addr value in access log. Also that API call returns 502. But there is nothing wrong with upstream, we have other flows which works fine. I went over the docs and other threads but couldn't find anything why would Nginx(A) unable to choose the server in server block.

Below is the nginx upstream block which I have in the config.

```
upstream backend {
    server test.example1.com;
    server test.example2.com down;

}
```